# plotly visualisation is too slow for United states county map

Tags: r, plotly

My data set has about 90K rows with follwing columns

```
state_name, county_name, county_lat, count_long, value_x
```

A similar direct example just for California counties [here](https://plot.ly/r/county-level-choropleth/)

Although it works fine for one sate, when I do for all the states in US, the plot is slow when i try to zoom in and out and also hovering data takes time to load. The plot generation itself takes a bit of time

Is there any solution to overcome this lag? If not, are there interactive plots like `plotly` that has hover and zoom features and visually colourful to plot maps?

Comment: You may want to have a look at `leaflet` and `shiny`: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html

Comment: what version of plotly do you have installed?

Comment: @MattSummersgill 4.7.1

Comment: @DJack Thanks. I have not worked in shiny. Will have a look :)

Comment: Hmm. This is a tough one to answer without knowing more details-- if you could post your code, profile using [Profvis](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/), and then attach the Profviz output that might provide a better starting point.

Comment: @MattSummersgill My code is exactly the same as given in the link[link] (https://plot.ly/r/county-level-choropleth/) . Just remove the filter for California and do it for all the sates.

Comment: In the example you provided, only the californiaPopulation.csv is provided. So we need access to all the data to run your example. Providing a reproducible example would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the issue here seems to be that the `plotly` `R` API does not appear to support using different colors for fill and border on polygon features.

One trade-off you might be able to make is to accept the fact that the line color can't be modified independently to avoid plotting every polygon twice.By not plotting the lines-only trace, hover info works pretty smoothly, and re-rendering speed on zoom is improved slightly for this set of polygons with ~88,000 vertices.

The resulting .html output file *(a decent proxy for how much processing will be necessary for web browser interaction)* of the method without the extra line trace is 7.7 MB on disk compared to 12.1MB if you use methods in the example.

However, the aesthetic difference is significant, and might not be an acceptable trade-off for many.

I know many of these features are still in their early stages, so perhaps some ongoing work will result in performance improvements for cases like this sooner than later.

From the R render-time side, there's technically room for improvement by re-writing the `plotly` internals like `Map()` and `tracify()` to use `data.table` for faster sorting than the current `dplyr::arrange` methods and it's `%chin%` function for faster character matching, but honestly I think that might fall more in the realm of premature optimization. Since the browser takes way longer to render the output than it does `R` to create it, I think the sub-second render time here might not be a big issue. *(After the updates in v4.6.0, it's pretty easy to generate browser crashing plots in 1-2 seconds on the R side.)*

From the HTML payload and javascript side, I'm sure improvements could be made, but I wouldn't know where to start.

In the meantime, some decent options might be down-sampling your data where you can, using the `raster` package and `shiny` to handle the heavy lifting on the server side instead of in browser, or investigating other tools.

#### Generate data

---

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

DT_counties <- setDT(map_data("county"))

## Islands of san juan in washington are represented by 2 groups and throw everything haywire
DT_counties <- DT_counties[!(region == "washington" & subregion == "san juan")]

## Create a coloring based on the raw number of vertices since we don't have population for all
DT_counties[,pop_cat := as.numeric(.N), by = .(group)]
DT_counties[,pop_cat := ordered(cut(pop_cat,10))]
```

#### Render as in example:

---

```
DT_counties %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  plot_geo(x = ~long, y = ~lat, color = ~pop_cat,
           text = ~subregion, 
           mode = "lines",
           colors = c('#ffeda0','#f03b20'),
           hoverinfo = 'text') %>%
  add_polygons(line = list(width = 0.4)) %>%
  add_polygons(
    fillcolor = 'transparent',
    line = list(color = 'black', width = 0.5),
    showlegend = FALSE, hoverinfo = 'none'
  )  %>%
  layout(title = "US Counties by Number of Vertices",
         geo = list(scope = 'usa',
                    showland = TRUE,
                    landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
                    countrycolor = toRGB("gray80"))) -> Example

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(Example,"tmp_Example.html")
```

#### Render without doubling polygons to get black lines

---

```
DT_counties %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  plot_geo() %>%
  add_polygons(x = ~long, y = ~lat, color = ~pop_cat,
               text = ~subregion, 
               colors = c('#ffeda0','#f03b20'),
               hoverinfo = 'text',line = list(width = 0.4)) %>%
  layout(title = "US Counties by Number of Vertices",
         geo = list(scope = 'usa',
                    showland = TRUE,
                    landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
                    countrycolor = toRGB("gray80"))) -> Small

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(Small,"tmp_Small.html")
```

#### Visual Comparison

---

[image: with and without line polygons]

### Profiling Results (not a lot of meat on the bone here)

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I now get to understand! As an off topic, do you know know any visualization that can drill down states into county/city/zipcode level seamlessly?

Comment: The closest thing I can think of might be leaflet, not sure exactly how it handles added polygons at this kind of scale. One interesting package, googlePolylines, that I just heard about today from the RStudio Rviews blog about new packages in January does sound potentially relevant— R port of a google spatial down sampling algorithm that might improve performance: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/googlePolylines/vignettes/sfencode.html

Comment: I went through some of the code online to check about leaflet. It doesn't have lat and long details. I am not sure how to work with it. Can you please help me with any sample code. I will be having counties with same name that belong to different sates. I tried leaflet code in last answer iof this post [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243031/plot-county-level-data-with-tooltips-in-r). But it didn't work.

Comment: I haven’t really used leaflet very much, my knowledge on this one was more concentrated around Plotly than the general domain of geospatial analysis. I think if you were able to post a well framed, thoughtful,  leaflet specific question you might be able to get some knowledgeable answers from the folks in the R spatial community!